# C#: К выделить весь текст в ячейке при фокусе

Tags: c#, datagrid, devexpress

Добрый день.

Есть два случая:

1. Когда пользователь кликает в **текст-бокс** на форме, как сделать так чтобы выделился весь текст?
2. **GridControl** (DevExpress) - грид, в колонку которого пользователь может вводить текст. По-умолчанию, там уже есть текст "0,00". Как сделать, чтобы когда пользователь активирует ячейку (кликает туда мышкой) весь текст выделялся?

Подозреваю, что оно похожим образом делается.

Спасибо.

---

**UPD**

1. Решение вопроса мне подсказал Javascript:

   textBox1.Select(0, textBox1.Text.Length);
2. ??

Answer (score 1):

Этот вариант уже пробовали?

Добавить в событие клика по текстбоксу:

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
textBox1.SelectionLength = textBox1.Text.Length;
```

Comment: Для поля ввода такой способ подходит, спасибо. А вот сгридом проблема